# I don't know why the computer shows "variable-sized object may not be initialized", can somone help me please?

Tags: c

```
int main(void)
{
  const int SIZE= 5;
  int grades[SIZE]={78, 67, 92, 83, 88}; // variable-sized object may not be initialized
...
}
```

After compiling it, the computer shows " variable-sized object may not be initialized" and I dont want to replace SIZE with number 5  in the array, so can someone help me with this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: That is because you are using a variable to determine the size. A variable is not a constant, hence is variable.

Comment: Instead of `const int` use `#define SIZE 5`

Comment: In C, a `const`-qualified variable is not a *constant expression*, so this is a *variable-length array* declaration, meaning its size is not determined until runtime.  Among other limitations, VLAs may not be declared with an initializer.  For this case, define `SIZE` as a macro as shown by Paul Ogilvie.

Comment: In short, const variables in C can actually change in some cases, so the standard just says that what you are doing is wrong, even if it's correct in your particular case.